# Is there a way to change a function's arguments from another javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change function arguments inside another function and then returns it to callee function. I'm trying something like this:

```
function func(a,b,c) {
    console.log(arguments, a, b, c); //[1, true, "a"] 1 true "a"
  arguments[0] = 2;
    console.log(arguments, a, b, c); //[2, true, "a"] 2 true "a"
  arguments = ArgumentsToNumber.apply(this, arguments);
  console.log(arguments, a, b, c); //[2, 1, NaN] 2 true "a"
}

function ArgumentsToNumber() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    arguments[i] = Number(arguments[i]);
  }
  return arguments;
}

func(1, true, 'a');
```

I want changes in `a`, `b` and `c` variables.

Comment: Why not just use `array.map` in `func`? `arguments = arguments.map((argument) => Number(argument))`

Comment: @AkshatMahajan That will thrown an error. arguments is not an array

Comment: This doesn't look like good practice `arguments[0] = 2`. You probably want to convert the arguments to an array first. `[].slice.call(arguments)` or map over them in some way like `[].map.call(arguments, callback)`

Comment: You must borrow `map` from array e.g. `[].map.call(arguments, Number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the Arguments object itself, instead of using it as an array-like in `apply`:

```
function func(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a, b, c); // 1, true, "a"
  arguments[0] = 2;
  console.log(a, b, c); // 2, true, "a"
  argumentsToNumber(arguments);
  console.log(a, b, c); // 2,    1, NaN
}
function argumentsToNumber(args) {
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    args[i] = +args[i];
}
func(1, true, 'a');
```

Note that changing the arguments in another function has bad performance.

Comment: @HenriCavalcante See for example http://www.jspatterns.com/arguments-considered-harmful/

Comment: it's `arguments.callee` or passing the whole `arguments` object that slows things down, but even those don't slow down code very much. http://www.3site.eu/jstests/arguments.callee.calls.html?times=50000